# Setting SO_RCVBUF decreases window scaling factor

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a small Android application written in C++ that opens a TCP socket to my HTTP server (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`) and sends a header. With no further configuration, this is the SYN sent by the device:

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 47262 (47262), Dst Port: 8000 (8000), Seq: 0, Len: 0
    Source Port: 47262
    Destination Port: 8000
    [Stream index: 47]
    [TCP Segment Len: 0]
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Header Length: 40 bytes
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    Window size value: 65535
    [Calculated window size: 65535]
    Checksum: 0x54cb [validation disabled]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (20 bytes), Maximum segment size, SACK permitted, Timestamps, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale
        Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes
        TCP SACK Permitted Option: True
        Timestamps: TSval 3637366, TSecr 0
        No-Operation (NOP)
        Window scale: 7 (multiply by 128)
```

The window size is 65,535 and the Window scale factor is 7, so implicitly the client is saying that its receive buffer is 65,535 * 2 ^ 7 = 8,388,480.

Now, I'm adding the following lines to the code:

```
unsigned long receive_buffer_size = 65535*127;
res = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &receive_buffer_size, sizeof(receive_buffer_size));
```

These lines come after opening the socket with `socket()`, but before connecting it to the port using `connect()`.

I would think that this would not affect the receive buffer, since we are providing the same values as those set by default. However, here's the result:

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 47263 (47263), Dst Port: 8000 (8000), Seq: 0, Len: 0
    Source Port: 47263
    Destination Port: 8000
    [Stream index: 2]
    [TCP Segment Len: 0]
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Header Length: 40 bytes
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    Window size value: 65535
    [Calculated window size: 65535]
    Checksum: 0xcf44 [validation disabled]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (20 bytes), Maximum segment size, SACK permitted, Timestamps, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale
        Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes
        TCP SACK Permitted Option: True
        Timestamps: TSval 3698768, TSecr 0
        No-Operation (NOP)
        Window scale: 5 (multiply by 32)
```

The receive buffer has decreased to 65,535 * 2 ^ 5 = 2,097,120. How is this to be explained?

Before and after setting the parameter, I'm writing the SO_RCVBUF using the following line:

```
res = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &curr_value, &optlen);
```

Before setting the parameter, SO_RCVBUF is 1,048,576 - nowhere near the default value we saw in the first snif. Afterwards, it is 2,097,152  which is not what I provided using `setsockopt()`. The last number is in the same order of magnitude as we saw in the second snif, so at least there's some consistency there.

Note that for every call, `res` is positive, so `getsockopt()` and `setsockopt()` always succeeded.

I could understand that the OS is maintaining a limit for setting SO_RCVBUF, but why is it lower than the default value? And why does reading SO_RCVBUF before setting any value result in a lower value than the default value?

Comment: The values you use to set the default are often not the default values. Some platform double the values you provide. Others adjust it up or down in various ways. I suggest you *get* the buffer size after you set it to see what the system really gave you.

Comment: @EJP After I set it, the buffer size is 2,097,152, which is around the value we see in the snifs. Can we therefore assume that the platform does not double the value on TCP level compared to the one we're getting in the program?

Comment: What are values of `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` and `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default`?

Comment: They are 1048576 and 229376 respectively. I don't know how to draw any conclusions from this: The `rmem_max` is exactly the number I'm getting from `getsockopt()` before changing the parameter, but then again the snif suggests the max buffer size is larger at that time. Moreover, after `setsockopt()`, it is twice the maximum.

Comment: @Aegonis, one more question: what is the value returned by `getsockopt()` _after_ you called `connect()`?

Comment: @gudok Just tried it. It is 2,097,152 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Actual window size for SYN segment is not subject for scaling. E.g. it equals to exactly 65535 in your example and not to 8,388,480 as you calculated. This is because client doesn't know yet whether receiving side supports window scaling or not. Window scale field acts like notification that sending side supports window scaling and that window sizes for further segments must be calculated as `window_size<<window_scale`.

Example:

1. Client sends SYN with "Window size value"=29200, "Window scale"=7. Actual window size is 29200 at this moment.
2. Client receives ACK,SYN
3. Client sends ACK with "Window size value"=229. Actual window size equals to 229 * 2^7 = 29312.

So, you need to look into further segments to find out actual window size.

Comment: _Window scale field acts like notification that sending side supports window scaling_ : Isn't that what SO_RCVBUF is setting? I am aware that at the moment of the SYN, the window size is not the value we're setting. The question is rather about the supported window size than the actual window size at the time of the SYN.